# Set tag using jQuery on change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html `select` tag:

```
<select name="title_'+ field +'" class="form-control form_select_tag">
    <option value="h1">h1</option> 
    <option value="h2">h2</option> 
    <option value="h3">h3</option> 
    <option value="h4">h4</option> 
    <option value="h5">h5</option> 
    <option value="h6">h6</option> 
</select>
```

Now, I want to get the value from this select tag and set the value to a variable called `tag`. for that I am using the below code:

```
var label   =   $(this).find('.form_input_label').val();
var name    =   $(this).find('.form_input_name').val();

if ( data_type === 'title' ) {

    var placeholder     =   $(this).find('.form_input_placeholder').val();                
    var tag             =   'h3';

    $('.form_select_tag').change(function() {
        tag     =   $(this).val();                    
    });


    html += '<' + tag + '>' + label + '</' + tag + '>';
}
```

now, in this line: `html += '<' + tag + '>' + label + '</' + tag + '>';` variable `tag` value is not set :(

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call `$('.form_select_tag').val();` directly instead `$(this).val();`

and next problem is

```
$('.form_select_tag').change(function() {...});
```

Is set command not get if you want to do that you need set `var tag` as global

`var tag` will not be **re-declare every functions call**

That is what you need right?

```js
createResult();
$('.form_select_tag , .form_input_label').on('change input', function() {
  createResult();
});


function createResult() {
  var html = '<br>Result:<br>'; //your code here
  var data_type = 'title'; //your code here

  var label = $('.form_input_label').val();
  var name = $('.form_input_name').val();
  if (data_type === 'title') {
    var placeholder = $('.form_input_placeholder').val();
    var tag = 'h3'
    tag = $('.form_select_tag').val();
    html += '<' + tag + '>' + label + '</' + tag + '>';
  }
  
  $('.label').html(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="title_'+ field +'" class="form-control form_select_tag">
  <option value="h1">h1</option>
  <option value="h2">h2</option>
  <option value="h3">h3</option>
  <option value="h4">h4</option>
  <option value="h5">h5</option>
  <option value="h6">h6</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form_input_label" value="label">

<label class="label">Male</label>
```

Comment: Yes, I am looking for this but you have created full code using your style. Can you set it according to my style? Cause new in jQuery :(

Comment: Style ? mean CSS?

Comment: i dont know what is `data_type`

Comment: i have set data_type attribute to a div to get some value.

Comment: if get as `string` and have word is **"title"** right?

Comment: Look, my code was completely okay, I just need to get the select value and then want to set to a var tag. Yes if it's `title` then will work.

Comment: but i haven't seem all your I hard to guess LOL

Comment: Thanks for your updated code but you see that I have to use html += 'soemthing';

Comment: Just copy and paste your code but seems not working :(

Comment: one more thing can we use if statement outside of function?

Comment: and you can like `if(...){createResult();}`

Comment: Hi, I small issues, when I change the select option then it doesn't show the changes immediately

Comment: change `$('.form_select_tag , .form_input_label').on('change input', function(){})` to
`$('.form_input_label').on('input', function(){})`

Comment: or other eventlistener as you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198464/discussion-between-creativeartbd-and-im-limit).